# OpenTelemetry for Kogito Workflow

Tags: redhat, open-telemetry, kie, kogito

I have tried using Kogito Workflow for orchestrating an event driven flow with multiple steps in the flow and communication protocol used for each step is via async mode with kafka. When I try to integrate OpenTelemetry for the Kogito workflow, it is creating a different traceparent context for different steps. Is there a way to properly integrate OpenTelemetry with Kogito Workflows to be able to track all the steps with since trace.

The document I tried for setting up OpenTelemetry is https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#cdi

Comment: What you really ask is how to use the same context in an entire workflow. OpenTelemetry is already working

Comment: Do you want to trace metrics for each step? For that, I believe you need a custom listener. But this is an interesting use case. Can you open an issue here? https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-runtimes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried integrating opentelemetry and each stage is an async API call with an immediate next state being wait operation waiting for response. For me, the trace context is not being retained and it is using a different traceId whenever it transitions to a new step in workflow. External systems where async call is being made are ensuring same trace context is being returned. Can you please provide an example if that is working correctly for you. Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoZanini I'm trying to find a way where I can trace complete workflow execution with a single traceId. Based on response from Panagiotis, I'll plan to open an issue for this if that is not working.